# Не получается передать данные $SESSION между двумя файлами php. Каждый раз создается новая сессия (смотрю session_id)

Tags: php, reactjs, phpmyadmin, сессия, axios

Я считываю данные из реакт-проекта с помощью axios. Передаю его в index.php для авторизации пользователя.

**index.php**
Тут происходит вход клиента и сессия выдает нужный результат.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
session_start();
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '3dmod');
if (!$connect){
    die('ERROR');
}
if(mysqli_connect_error()){
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
else{
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_login` = 
    '$login' AND `user_password` = 
    '$password'";
    $res = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        $check_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        unset($_SESSION['user']);
        echo session_id();
        $_SESSION['user'] = [
            "id" => $check_user['user_id'],
            "login" => $check_user['user_login'],
            "email" => $check_user['user_email'],
            "password" => $check_user['user_password']
        ];
    }
    echo $_SESSION['user']['login'];
    echo ' ';
    echo $_SESSION['user']['email'];
    echo ' ';
    echo $_SESSION['user']['password'];
    echo ' ';
    echo $_SESSION['user']['id'];
    
    if($check_user){
        echo "Success!";
    }
    else{
        echo "Error!";
    }
}
?>
```

Передаю сессию в profile.php, но тут уже session_id показывает совершенно другое и откуда-то вместо нужных мне данных берется $SESSION['user']['id'] = 30.

```
<?php

session_start();
//var_dump($_SESSION);
echo session_id();

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', '3dmod');

if (!$connect){
die('ERROR');
}

if(mysqli_connect_error()){
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
else{
    echo $_SESSION['user']['login'];
    echo ' ';
    echo $_SESSION['user']['email'];
    echo ' ';
    echo $_SESSION['user']['password'];
    echo ' ';
    echo $_SESSION['user']['id'];
    echo ' ';

    if($_SESSION['user']){
        echo "Success!";
    }
    else{
        echo "Error!";
    }
}
?>
```

Данные я берру из phpmyadmin, а отправляю всё это в реакт-проект. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. var_dump() на второй странице показал следующее:

```
array(1) { ["user"]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "30" ["login"]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["password"]=> string(0) "" } }
```

Comment: ну вы же сами и запускаете дважды сессию. Зачем?